# Add Property in TypeScript - DiscordJS

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot in TypeScrypt, well, what happens is that I don't know how to declare one more variable to a Discord property. I'll try to explain better, with 2 examples of what happens to me when I do it in JavaScript, and in TypeScript...

[JavaScript]

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
   let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guildId);
   guild.config = {
     config1: "value1",
     ...
   }
  // NoErrors.
console.log(guild.config);
// Return {
     config1: "value1",
     ...
  }
});
```

[TypeScript]

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
   let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guildId);
   guild.config = {
     config1: "value1",
     ...
   }
  // Error in code editor: Property 'config' does not exist on type 'Guild'.
```

Well, in short. I would like to know how I can add the "config" property in "Guild".

Comment: It's possible to do this with casts, but generally TypeScript would encourage you to create a new object to store this information, rather than tacking it onto an existing one.

Comment: That's also not a reliable way of storing your "configs" for each guild, as discord.js decides when to clear them from the cache.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, it is simply so that later, it will be easier for me to obtain information about a server